# strtoint not be getting the same value

Tags: delphi

in my second variable 'm trying to convert string to integer but the value is not the same!

the variable "app" be receiving '1' , but it was to receive ' 0001.

here is my code:

```
function isnew(Ls:string):Boolean;
var
appvs,app:Integer;
begin
      appvs:=StrToInt(StringReplace(GetAppVersionStr,'.',''[rfReplaceAll]));
      app:= strtoint(Ls); // the value in ls is 0001 but receive in app 1
      if app > appvs then
      result:= True
      else
      result:= false;

end;
```

Comment: What integer value do you expect the string '0001' represent?

Comment: I'm not laughing, neither crying. I just don't understand your question, because it implies you think that an integer value expressed as 0001 is different than 1.

Comment: I was confused 1000 with 0001

Comment: I was stressed with some errors.

Comment: Perhaps this will help: A value of `1000` can be broken out into simple math based on the number of digits: `1 * 1000 + 0 * 100 + 0 * 10 + 0 * 1 = 1000 + 0 + 0 + 0 = 1000`. Let's do the same with `0001`: `(0 * 1000 + 0 * 100 + 0 * 10 + 1 * 1= 0 + 0 + 0 + 1 = 1`. So `0001 = 1`. Does that explain it?

Comment: Perhaps OP's native language is one which reads backwards, thus the confusion of `1000` vs. `0001`.

Comment: @Jerry: The math I demonstrated works the same way in reverse order.

Comment: @Ken Indeed, my comment was targeted at Tom (whose other comments are deleted now) - I don't know if such languages reverse numbers too (I'm talking about nationality languages, not programming languages).

Comment: @Jerry: I didn't see anything addressing it to Tom. AFAIK,  RTL languages don't reverse Arabic numerals. `1000` in English = `1000` in Arabic in everything I've ever seen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Numbers can have different representations. So 1 and 0001 are different representations of the same number. An `Integer` stores the number rather than the representation. So, you cannot differentiate 1 from 0001 in an `Integer`.

Answer (score 1):

`app:Integer` holds the integer representation of `Ls:string`.

You can't "force" an integer to be represented as a 4-digit value unless its value is really somewhere in `[1000,9999]`.
Your display can because this is a string.